# What is a factorial prior?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, factorial, information-theory, bayesian

I am not entirely sure what a *factorial prior* is (e.g. as used [here](https://www.uni-muenster.de/Physik.TP/~lemm/papers/dens/node9.html)), and I don't see any good explanations anywhere either (it seems everyone expects it to be known).
I am sure it is a relatively simple concept, but I would just like to be sure that I understand it.

Any help is very welcome, especially ones that focus on the intuition.

Comment: I didn't know the term, but it seems to me that they just mean "a prior that factorizes".

Comment: So anything on the form $p({\bf z}) = \prod_i p(z_i)$?

Comment: Yes, I would think, but I might be wrong.